# “Password change date” or “Change password date”?

Tags: adverbs

Is the date that a user changes his password, "password change date" or "change password date"? Any general guideline?

Comment: "Password change" and "change password" are not the same. Your first version is correct.

Comment: Thanks. what is the difference?

Comment: @PHPst `password change date` refers to 'password' as the subject of the sentence, ergo, `change date` insinuates that the date the password was changed. > `change password date` is with the `change` being the subject - and insinuates one should change the date of the password.

Comment: @3kstc Thanks. Please convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: @PHPst converted to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with "passsword change date". This uses the noun form of change, so it is the date on which the password was changed.

Merriam-Webster:

> 1  the act, process, or result of changing

"change password date" uses the verb form of change, so it is probably a request to change the "password date".

Merriam-Webster:

> transitive verb
>   1
>   a :  to make different in some particular

Answer (score 0):

*"Password change date"* refers to 'password' as the subject of the sentence, ergo, change date insinuates that the date the password was changed.

*"Change password date"* is with the 'change' being the subject - and insinuates one should change the date of the password

Comment: @PHPst If there is anything unclear please let me know, if not could you please kindly select the answer! :D Thanks